# Resize text inside <pre> element like <textarea>

Tags: javascript, dom, text, google-chrome-extension, pre

I want to resize my text inside `pre` element like `textarea`, for example if you set columns of `textarea` equal to 10 and your text exceeds that, then the text will go to next line.

How can I do that with `pre` element? What is the technical term?

Note that I need to use `pre` element because it reads `\n` and `\r`, and `textarea` does not allow to append a button under it (why?).

An example:

[image]

I present a dummy scenario below (working code) to illustrate my issue(s).

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <button onclick="call()">Click</button>
        </body>
        <script>
     function call(){
    view = window.open("","Viewer", "width=400,height=600, resizable=no");
    view.document.write('<div id="id_1"</div>');
        t=["asdf", "sasdfasdfasdfasdfasd", "sasdfasdfasdfasdfasd"]
        id = view.document.getElementById("id_1");
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    
            if (i % 2 == 0){
            
            ed_1 = document.createElement("pre");
            ed_1.id = "edt_"+i;
            ed_1.textContent = t[i];
            id.appendChild(ed_1);
            
            prnt = view.document.getElementById("edt_"+i);
            edb_1 = document.createElement("button");
            nextline_gap_1 = document.createElement("br");      
            edb_1.innerHTML = "Button no = "+i;
            edb_1.id = i;
            prnt.appendChild(nextline_gap_1);           
            prnt.appendChild(edb_1);    
                              }
                              else{
           text_a = document.createElement("textarea");     
            text_a.readOnly = "true";
            text_a.cols = "10"; 
            text_a.id = "edt_"+i;
            text_a.textContent = t[i];
            id.appendChild(text_a);
            
            
            prnt = view.document.getElementById("edt_"+i);
            edb_1 = document.createElement("button");
            nextline_gap_1 = document.createElement("br");      
            edb_1.innerHTML = "Button no = "+i;
            edb_1.id = i;
            prnt.appendChild(nextline_gap_1);           
            prnt.appendChild(edb_1);          
                             } } }
        </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your code :

1. You should avoid using the [`onevent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers) attributes, like `onclick="call()"`, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.
2. You should avoid using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), it's better to create a [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) and append it to the popup.
3. You do not need to manually loop over your array, just use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
4. You have not [declared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#declarations) any of your variables.
5. You code is not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You have repeated statements that could be written only once higher in the scope.
6. You do not need to select elements that you have appended to the popup because you already have a reference to them.
7. You cannot nest a `button` **inside** of a `textarea`.
8. You should use CSS [margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) to add white-space, not [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) elements. These are meant to be used for linebreaks inside a paragraph only.
9. [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) elements have a specific white-space behavior that is different from other elements. You can override this with the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property. You can also control [wrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text) of long unbroken strings of text with the [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) property.
10. You can omit the `cols` attribute (which is based on average character width) and give your `<pre>` and `<textarea>` elements the same width using CSS `rem` or `em` [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_font) which are based on the width of a capital `M` at the current font size.

Below you will find your code re-written in a way that accounts for all of the above points. Let me know if there is any aspect of it that you do not understand and I will explain further.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Pre-Wrap Test </title>
<button id="trigger">Click</button>
<script>
  let trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
  trigger.addEventListener('click', injectContent);

  let text = [
    'asdf',
    'sasdfasdfasdfasdfasd',
    'sasdfasdfsdfgh\nsdfasdfasddfghjk'
  ];

  function injectContent() {
    let view = window.open('', 'Viewer', 'width=400, height=600, resizable=no');
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    
    style.textContent = `
      pre {
        overflow-wrap: anywhere;
        white-space: normal;
      }
      
      textarea, pre {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
        width: 8em;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
      }

      .wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }
    `;
    
    fragment.append(style);

    text.forEach((t, i) => {
      let out = document.createElement('div');
      let btn = document.createElement('button');
      let box;

      out.className = 'wrapper';

      btn.textContent = `Button no = ${i}`;
      btn.id = `btn-${i}`;
      
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        box = document.createElement('pre');
      } else {
        box = document.createElement('textarea');
        box.readOnly = "true";
      }

      box.id = `edt_${i}`;
      box.textContent = t;
      
      out.append(box);
      out.append(btn);
      
      fragment.append(out);
    });
    
    view.document.body.replaceChildren(fragment);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have not read through all of your code, but I see a typo here with the **double** closing braces: "box.id = `edt_${i}}`;". But if it is intended, could you enlight me?

Comment: Ah, yes I see, I did not catch that typo as there is no code which actually selects these elements by id. It has been corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, as a beginner I learned a lot from your answer, but if you could kindly explain a bit more, specifically, that would be nice. I want to know exactly what resized inside `<\pre>`, and can I do that like `ed_1.id = "edt_"+i;ed_1.textContent = t[i];`, .....Are keeping `pre` and `button` elements in `Div` then resizing `div` element? if not then what property (like  `ed_1.id = "edt_"+i;ed_1.textContent = t[i];`) can do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you're asking but I'll try to explain. The `<div>` itself does not control the wrapping, that is enabled by the declarations in the `pre { ... }` rule in `style.textContent`. The point at which the text wraps is controlled by the `width` property in the `pre, textarea { ... }` rule. You can press `Ctrl+Shift+I` with the popup open to access the inspector and [see this](https://i.imgur.com/P1YPyHb.png). Also, `t[i]` is not valid inside the `forEach` loop. Just `t` is the value of the array item and `i` is it's index. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

**Some `<pre>` information**

The `<pre>` tag defines preformatted text.

Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed exactly as written in the HTML source code.

Most browsers will display the `<pre>` element with the following default values:

```
pre {
  display: block;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

[Source (w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

**My understanding and explanation**

The `<pre>` default values are not the same than the `textarea`, but it is possible to use some CSS to override those.

You may want to try to type some text and play with the size of the resizable `<pre>` element in the snippet below to check if that fits your needs.

```css
pre {
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre contenteditable="true"></pre>
```

As fas as I understand, you were trying to find the `white-space` property.
By default, the `<pre>` `white-space` property is `pre` for "preserved".
( Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `br` elements. )

I have overriden it to `pre-wrap` in my CSS to match what I think you meant.
( Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes. )

[More information about `white-space` (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

**Note about `<textarea>`**

```css
textarea {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<br/>
<button>Click</button>
```

By changing the `white-space` CSS property, the `<textarea>` element can behave the same as the `<pre>` element.
I don't think there is something preventing a `<button>` to be appended after a `<textarea>`.
Would it be possible that your code appends the `<button>` after an element that is *before* the `<textarea>` ?